# How to get days , weeks and months between two specific dates given using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, calendar

I'm working on a loan management system using NodeJS for the Back End and AngularJS for the front end. Simply this is what I need to do.

There are 3 categories in the system.

1. Daily Loans
2. Weekly Loans
3. Monthly loans

Loan amount is `$5000` and this is a `Weekly loan`. It mean customer need to pay this loan weekly basis.

Start date is 2018-12-11 ( December 11 , 2018)

End date is 2019-05-11 (April 11 , 2019)

Interest rate is `8%`.

What I want to do is , find all the weeks between start date and end date.
And also today is Tuesday and in every Tuesday of week, customer need to do a payment. So I need to save that repayments list when adding a new loan.

**Simply I want to count 7 days from 2018-12-11 till 2019-05-11. And specially we need to skip holidays. It's being saved in the system. When we are calculating the dates, we can check that from holiday list and skip them.**

This is a sample output I want :

Date : 2018-12-11 , Amount : $xx

Date : 2018-12-18 , Amount : $xx

Date : 2018-12-25 , Amount : $xx

Date : 2019-01-01 , Amount : $xx

Date : 2019-01-08 , Amount : $xx

Date : 2019-01-15 , Amount : $xx
.
.
.

What I have tried some far.

I tried to use `https://momentjs.com/` and tried to get weeks like this :

`moment().add(10, 'days').calendar();` -> From this we can add all the dates and get the date after 10 days.

And also I used `https://github.com/datejs/Datejs` for this and still didn't get a way to loop all the dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) module in NodeJS.

```
npm i moment
```

It has a function [`.diff`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), from the docs:

```
//moment().diff(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array);
//moment().diff(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array, String);
//moment().diff(Moment|String|Number|Date|Array, String, Boolean);

var a = moment([2007, 0, 29]);
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28]);
a.diff(b, 'days') // 1
```

**EDIT:**
So basically, You want to +7 days excluding holidays.

Below is a very basic loop based solution. But there are libraries doing what you want.

```
const start = moment().startOf('day');
const end = moment(somedate).startOf('day');
let current = start;
const holidayList = [[2018, 11, 25]]
while(current.isSameOrBefore(end)){
    let nextWeek = moment(current).add(7, 'days');
    //check if holidays are between nextWeek and current
    //get number of holidays
    const number_of_holidays = holidayList.reduce((p,c)=>{
        if(moment(c).isAfter(current) && moment(c).isSameOrBefore(nextWeek)){
            return p+1;
        }
        return p;
    },0)
    nextWeek = nextWeek.add(number_of_holidays, 'days')
    //do something
    console.log('---'+nextWeek.toDate());
    current = nextWeek;
}
```

You can checkout [momentjs-business](https://github.com/leonardosantos/momentjs-business) or [moment-weekday-calc](https://github.com/andruhon/moment-weekday-calc).

**Edit 2:** From the github issue I can see that you only need Tuesdays, without the holiday.

```
const end = moment(endDate).startOf('day');
const holidayList = [[2018, 11, 25]]
const dayINeed = 2; //for tuesday
let current = moment().isoWeekday();
if (current <= dayINeed) { 
    current = moment().isoWeekday(dayINeed).startOf('day');
} else {
    current = moment().add(1, 'weeks').isoWeekday(dayINeed).startOf('day');
}
while(current.isSameOrBefore(end)){
    /* HERE check for holiday */
    console.log(current.toArray());
    current.add(1, 'weeks');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer bro. One question, like I said, can we count by 7 days and take the exact date ? Like I have shown in the question ? ( Dates List ) ? Exactly Tuesday by counting 7 days ?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: finally can you please check this ? https://github.com/andruhon/moment-weekday-calc/issues/18  
Thank you so much for your great HELP

Comment: According to this you just need Tuesdays except the holidays. You can just `moment().isoWeekday(2)` then add 1 week. `moment().add(1, 'weeks')` and check for holidays in the list. it's pretty simple no need for libraries.

Comment: Edited the answer.